# Basic Number Theory (Divisibility)

Tags: number-theory

Not sure where to start. Thank you in advance!

Find all positive integers $n$ such that $12$ divides $n$ and $n$ divides $816$.

Comment: Hint: Prime factorization.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n = 12k$, then $816 = pn = p(12k)\implies pk = 68\implies k \mid 68\implies k = 1,  2, 4, 17, 34, 68\implies n = 12, 24, 48, 204, 408, 816.$

Answer (score 0):

We have $816 = 2^4 \cdot 3 \cdot 17$ and $12 = 2^2 \cdot 3$ so
$n = 12 k$ and
$$
\frac{816}{n} = \frac{2^4 \cdot 3 \cdot 17}{2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot k} = \frac{2^2\cdot 17}{k}
$$ 
which means $k \in \{ 1, 2, 4, 17, 2\cdot 17, 2^2 \cdot 17 \}$ and $n \in \{ 12, 24, 48, 204, 408, 816 \}$